# Convert C/C++ #if and #elif directive to C#

Tags: c#, c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to convert **C**/C++ code to C# programatically. I have encountered a problem when converting preprocessor directives, especially with `#if` and `#elif` since the preprocessor for **C**/C++ accepts more conditions. So, this will not compile in C#.

Based on what I've read the C# preprocessor only accepts `==`, `!=`, `&&`, and `||`.
But for **C**, it is possible to have arithmetic operators for addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, bitwise operations, shifts, comparisons, and logical operations. In addition, unlike **C** and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol; the `#if` statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

I will be able to handle `==` and `!=` but how about for the other conditions?

Comment: How about using as a pre-processing the preprocessor for C

Answer (score 1):

This was a design decision of the original C# spec. It was deemed that the C++ preprocessor was too powerful (the International Obfuscated C Code Contest has an entire section for worst abuse of this "feature").

So basically, no. C# has nothing like the C preprocessor.

However there is the concept of T4 templates, which you might be able to abuse in the same way that you do with the C preprocessor. This is code gen, rather than an in process transform of the code.....

PS. Have you considered using C++/CLI as opposed to C#.NET for your purposes? I assume you want to run legacy C/C++ code in process in .NET. C++/CLI is a much better language to use for porting code into .NET.